# How to select next row using navigation button?

Tags: java, swing, awt

Next Navigation button is not working as desired.

I'm already create previous navigation button to select previous row in my GUI but Next navigation button is not working as desired. When I select a row in the table and click Next Button it's going to select the last row in in the table. How I can solve this problem?

This is the screenshot of my project:

[image]

This is the Previous Navigation Button Code:

```
private void btPreviousActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    int rowCount = tbDataContact.getSelectedRow();

    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        tbDataContact.clearSelection();
        tbDataContact.changeSelection(i, 0, false, false);
        Object col = tbDataContact.getValueAt(rowCount, 0);
        //lbPrevious.setText(String.valueOf(rowCount));
        showSelectedRow(i);
    }
}
```

I expect the next button work like previous button.

This is Next Buttton code:

```
private void btNextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

    int row = tbDataContact.getSelectedRow();
    int rowCount = tbDataContact.getRowCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount ; i++) {
        tbDataContact.clearSelection();
        tbDataContact.changeSelection(i, i, true, false);

        // get the column number and show in jlabel
        Object col = tbDataContact.getValueAt(i, 0);
        lbNext.setText(String.valueOf(rowCount));

        // Show data into form
        showSelectedRow(i); 
    }
}
```

---

This is Next Buttton code:

```
    private void btNextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

    int row = tbDataContact.getSelectedRow();
    int rowCount = tbDataContact.getRowCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount ; i++) {
        tbDataContact.clearSelection();
        tbDataContact.changeSelection(i, i, true, false);

        // get the column number and show in jlabel
        Object col = tbDataContact.getValueAt(i, 0);
        lbNext.setText(String.valueOf(rowCount));

        // Show data into form
        showSelectedRow(i); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [tour], read [ask], and post a proper [mre] that reproduces your issue. So far you posted the code of `previous` button, but your faulty code as per your description is the `next` button, but you didn't show any code. Also are you using Swing? Please read the links and [edit] your question to provide the missing information (code)

Comment: Can you update your question with Next Navigation Button Code so we can figure out why your next navigation button code is not working or where you are lacking?

Comment: @DushyantTankariya I included the code from OP's answer into the question, in case you want to take a look at it. I won't since OP seems like he doesn't even wants to read the links I provided or post a proper [mre].

Answer (score 1):

You've written Next Button listener,

```java
private void btNextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

    int row = tbDataContact.getSelectedRow();
    int rowCount = tbDataContact.getRowCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount ; i++) {
        tbDataContact.clearSelection();
        tbDataContact.changeSelection(i, i, true, false);

        // get the column number and show in jlabel
        Object col = tbDataContact.getValueAt(i, 0);
        lbNext.setText(String.valueOf(rowCount));

        // Show data into form
        showSelectedRow(i); 
    }
}
```

In which you have for loop which iterates from 0 to total no. of rows and every time you've used `changeSelection(i, i, true, false);`
Proper syntax for [ChangeSelection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#changeSelection(int,%20int,%20boolean,%20boolean))

```java
public void changeSelection(int rowIndex,
                   int columnIndex,
                   boolean toggle,
                   boolean extend)
```

Updates the selection models of the table, depending on the state of the two flags: `toggle` and `extend`. Most changes to the selection that are the result of keyboard or mouse events received by the UI are channeled through this method so that the behavior may be overridden by a subclass.

This implementation uses the following conventions:
**toggle & extend:**

```
 1. toggle: false, extend: false. Clear the previous selection and ensure the new cell is selected.
 2. toggle: false, extend: true. Extend the previous selection from the anchor to the specified cell, clearing all other selections.
 3. toggle: true, extend: false. If the specified cell is selected, deselect it. If it is not selected, select it.
 4. toggle: true, extend: true. Apply the selection state of the anchor to all cells between it and the specified cell.
```

From above you have used 3rd statement for Next button listener and 1st statement for the Previous button listener.

**Parameters:**

```
rowIndex - affects the selection at row
columnIndex - affects the selection at column
toggle - see description above
extend - if true, extend the current selection
```

In every iteration, it will change the selection by using `tbDataContact.changeSelection(i,i,true,false);` method.

---

Long story short point, Here you don't need to iterate loop for selection.
You can get the currently selected row by using `getSelectedRow()` and verify the condition that selected row is last or not if not then increase the row value and put it on `changeSelection(increasedIndexNo, ColumnIndex, toggle, index)`.

**Example:**

```java
int row = tbDataContact.getSelectedRow();
int rowCount = tbDataContact.getRowCount();
if(row<=rowCount){
    tbDataContact.clearSelection();
    tbDataContact.changeSelection(++row, 0, false, false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir. it's working when I change true value to false value. 
tbDataContact.changeSelection(++row, 0, false, false);